# Still permission denied after add "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, permissions, android-sdcard

---

solution: test target project must also add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in AndroidManifest.xml

this question came from an android test project,which can't write test result into SDcard. Add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE into test target project can solve this problem.

---

Always throw permission denied when I use code below to write xml file into emulator's sdcard.
I have added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
        @Override
public void onStart(){

    try {
        File root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        myWriter = new FileWriter(new File(root, TEST_RESULT+".xml"));          
        startResultOutput(myWriter);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("TestInfo", "after new FileWriter: "+e.getMessage());
    }
    super.onStart();

}
```

catched IOExcetion, the message was:
        after new FileWriter: /mnt/sdcard/InterFace_test_result.xml (Permission denied)

Below is the manifest code

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"></uses-permission>
```

SD card was mounted, because I can use another application to write file into external sd card.

Can anybody give me some suggestion?

PS:
the emulator system is 2.3.3

Comment: have you set up a sd memory card in the emulators params? in the interface where you can create it there is an option for that

Comment: yes~I can use another application to write file into my emualtor's sd card, and from adb shell ,I also can operate the sd card.

Comment: I got the same problem. do you solved this?

see my post: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877740/traceview-cant-write-sd-card

Comment: For the emulator ensure to have at least 512mb size of SDCard

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

What I can understand is,
You are adding `permission` two times

1. one time in `Application` tag as an attribute
2. and second time using `<use-permission>`

**Solution:**

Try removing any one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still can't work. I removed one perssion from application tag...

Answer (score 0):

You should add permission tag `<uses-permission>` before `<application>` tag.